# Ubuntu 16.04 does not load on iMac 2009

Tags: boot, mac

I'm new to ubuntu. I want to install ubuntu 16,04 on an iMac 2009 and I keep getting the same error line:

Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MDK states has failed: import_mok_state0 failed: Invalid Parameter
Confirming boot since secure mode is disabled

After that, the screen goes black.

The same error happened when I tried installing newer versions of Ubuntu.
How can I fix this?
I would appreciate any help: I'm really looking forward to working with Ubuntu on my Mac...

Thanks!

Comment: Is it 16.04 or 19.04?

Comment: Hi, Pilot6, thanks for stepping in. It's 16.04